# Overflow hidden causes div to be underneath floated div instead behind it

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow

Currently I have this situation of two `div`s next to each other (under one container div), one is floating left and the other one occupies 100% of its parent.

I also want that the scrollbar will be hidden, but the content will remain clipped (Managed to achieve this with `overflow: hidden`). However, when I used `overflow: hidden`, the floating arrangement changed and the div went underneath the floated one.

This is a snippet of the hierarchy with and without hiding the scrollbar:

```css
.d1{
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;     
    transition: width 0.5s;
    float: left;
}

.cont{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background: yellow;
}

.d2{
    background: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.d3{
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Without overflow:</h1>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="d1"></div>
  <div class="d3"></div>
</div>

<h1>With overflow:</h1>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="d1"></div>
  <div class="d2"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to meet both constraints (floating with one div behind the other with 100% occupation of the parent ANF hiding scrollbar but remain clipped).

**I was able to achieve the desired result by using `position: absolute` or `css grid`, but I want to avoid those solutions.**

Thanks.

Comment: flexbox? or inline block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `overflow:hidden` use `clip-path:inset(0)`. Both should produce the same result by clipping the overflowing content

```css
.d1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
  transition: width 0.5s;
  float: left;
}

.cont {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.d2 {
  background: blue;
  clip-path:inset(0);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>With overflow:</h1>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="d1"></div>
  <div class="d2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The clip was half helpful, the scorllbar still appears and also occupies height equal to the full content of d2 instead of 20px

Comment: Here's an example, scrollbar appears at the full window: https://codepen.io/avis-js/pen/PozqwaM

Comment: Actually, when creating this example, I met another problem (even with overflow: hidden) - the text isn't behind d1.

Comment: @SomoKRoceS simply add `overflow: hidden;` to .cont

Comment: Oh.. true.. hmm any ideas for the content (text in this case)?

Comment: @SomoKRoceS here is a trick using shape-outside: https://jsfiddle.net/wcj4mL1g/ since text should wrap around float ... but in your case position:absolute is a lot more suitable than this hack

Comment: It seems like this is too much hacky :) Is absolute the only option here? (Do you think I should open a new question for that?)

Comment: @SomoKRoceS not the only option but the most logical and easy one here. I don't know why you don't want to use it (like said in the question) but it does exactly what you want ... doesn't really deserve a new question. Either explain why you cannot/don't want to use absolute or simply accept the fact that it's the most suitable among all the other hacks

Answer (score 1):

I would like to explain a little bit about why you have the issue with overflow hidden.

**Without** `overflow: hidden`

d1 and d3 are overlapped, because d1 is set to `float: left`.

Why d1 is in front of d3? This is because d1 is set to position: relative and float, which make it has a greater stack order.

**With** `overflow: hidden`

Using the overflow property with a value different to visible (its default) will create a new block formatting context, and it will not an overlap with the float element, instead it will follow the previous element.

E.g. Set the width of d2 to less than 80px (100-20) will make d2 come up with d1

```css
.d1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: width 0.5s;
  float: left;
}

.cont {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.d2 {
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<h1>With overflow:</h1>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="d1"></div>
  <div class="d2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really need that d2 will be behind d1 (with its content). I mean, d1 will hide some of d2 text for example.